# Periodic cleavage of carbohydrates

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

Carbohydrate like glucose undergoes periodic cleavage by $\ce{HIO4}$ and forms respective products are five moles of formic acid and one mole of formaldehyde.

Here is my question , what is mechanism and what are the products by fructose with the same? Do we have any specific rules for that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are specific rules regarding the products of periodic acid cleavage of 1,2-diols (Malaprade reaction). As to the mechanism, it is illustrated [here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#carbohydrates). It is similar to the mechanism for KMnO<sub>4</sub> oxidation of 1,2-diols. The structures of the products of 1,2-cleavage of carbohydrates is a diagnostic tool used as an aid in determining their structures. The oxidative cleavage of ethylene glycol (**1**, Fig. 1) affords two equivalents of formaldehyde. **Primary alcohols give formaldehyde**. Cleavage of the first single bond in glycerol **2** necessarily affords formaldehyde and α-hydroxyacetaldehyde. Aldehydes are readily hydrated in water. As far as periodic acid is concerned, the hydrate is a 1,2-diol. Cleavage of the second C-C bond produces not only another equivalent of formaldehyde but also an equivalent of formic acid. **Secondary alcohols produce formic acid via aldehydes.** (continued)
[image: ![enter image description here]
From the foregoing information, D-glyceraldehyde (**3**, Fig. 2) yields formaldehyde from the primary alcohol and 2 equivalents of formic acid, one from the secondary alcohol and one from the aldehyde group. Cleavage of one C-C bond of 1,3-dihydroxyacetone (**4**) yields formaldehyde and glycolic acid, which in turn provides formaldehyde and CO<sub>2</sub>. **Ketones, and ultimately carboxyl groups, produce CO<sub>2</sub>.** The oxidative transformations are summarized in the red box in Fig. 2.
[image]
The expected products from periodic acid cleavage of D-glucose, D-mannitol and D-fructose are predicted below based upon the formulated rules.
[image]

Comment: can you pls share the link for the mechanism again ... this link is not working ! :)

Comment: @visheshjain: The link in the text has been corrected. Either of the first two items under [Carbohydrates](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#carbohydrates) contains the information.