# Hydrolysis of β-1,2 glycosidic bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, carbohydrates, hydrolysis

Are there any easy, not enzymatic, ways to hydrolyse $\beta$-1,2 glycosidic bonds like they occur in steviosids?

I thought of something like vinegar, which is commonly used to cleave the $\alpha$-1,2 glycosidic bond of saccharose when producing inverted sugar $-$ could that also work for the $\beta$-type?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By *easy* do you mean involving less energy, or less work to do? Or any other thing?

Comment: I mean less work to do, so one could do it at home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are non-enzymatic methods for removing the three glucose moieties of stevioside **1**. Unfortunately, dilute mineral acid hydrolysis not only removes the glucose entities but also effects Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement of the aglycone steviol **2** to isosteviol **3**.<sup>[1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031942290852255)</sup> While vinegar (5% aqueous acetic acid) is a weaker acid than hydrochloric acid, I am certain that it would have been tried to avoid the rearrangement of steviol **2**. Exposure of stevioside **1** with aqueous KOH effects saponification of the ester group leading to steviobioside **4**.---*continued*---
[image]
A more fruitful procedure that avoids rearrangement involves periodic acid cleavage of the five vicinal diols of the glucose units (marked in red in structure **1** below).<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qZbr.jpg)</sup> This procedure liberates hexa-aldehyde **5** in addition to two equivalents of formic acid.<sup>[3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29601/periodic-cleavage-of-carbohydrates/102529#102529)</sup>  Vigorous base treatment is required to saponify the hindered ester while base also liberates tetra-aldehyde entity by β-elimination forming steviol **2** in 75% yield. And NO, you can't do this at home.
[image]

1) [Avent, a. G., Hanson, J. R., de Oliveira, Bras H., *Phytochemistry*, **1990**, *29*, 2712.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031942290852255)
2) [Ogawa, T., Nozaki, M., Matsui, M., *Tetrahedron*, **1980**, *36*, 2641.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040402080801360)
3) On periodic acid cleavage of vicinal diols, see: [Periodic cleavage of carbohydrates](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29601/periodic-cleavage-of-carbohydrates/102529#102529)